# Filter empty space, null and undefined but keep `0`

Tags: javascript

I would like to keep `0` and need to remove `undefined`, `null` `''` `,,` from the array. I tried this:

```js
var array = [0, 1, null, 2, "", 3, undefined, 3,,,,,, 4,, 4,, 5,, 6,,,,];

var filtered = array.filter(function (el) {
  return el !== null
});

console.log(filtered);
```

But getting result as : `[0, 1, 2, '', 3, undefined, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6]`

if I add the condition as `return el != null`, still empty space exist and getting error from `lint`. how to handle this?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `return e || e === 0` to filter it

```js
var array = [0, 1, null, 2, "", 3, undefined, 3,,,,,, 4,, 4,, 5,, 6,,,,];

var filtered = array.filter(e =>{ 
  return e || e === 0
})

console.log(filtered);
```